# Ionic4 router back animation problem with NavController

Tags: angular, ionic4, router

[image]

I have a problem with animation on my Ionic 4 project. If I click the header's back-button the animation will be played first and after it the navigation stack will clear the previous page. This is my custom-header typescript file:

```
  constructor(public navCtr: NavController, ...) {
  }


   public goBack(): Promise<any> {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            try {
                this.navCtr.back({animated:true});
          }
...
   }
```

The problem is still here even if I use the default back button.

```
<!-- Default back button -->
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-back-button></ion-back-button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

The forward animation looks good, the problem is present only on the back flow. How can I fix it?

Comment: Maybe try to update Ionic. Here I found that they made some fixes about animations 2 days ago. https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/releases

Comment: thanks a lot. I have a lot of struggle with it. Thx

Comment: Did it solve the issue?

Comment: on android yes on iOS no

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
this.navCtrl.navigateback('youURL');
```

This may help you.

Comment: This currently does not provide animation.